# Windows File Server - file creation error

Tags: windows, network-share, file-sharing

We recently migrate our file server from win 2008R2 to a win2019. But from a network drive trying to create new folder or file will give you an error

`"refers to a location that is unavailable"`.

**Rights**

Users do not have rights to create file or folder at the root directory of the share (and this folder only) as you can see in the permission :
 [permission on root dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY65r.png)

but users do have rights to create/write in the sub folders, depending on the groups they are in. Inheritance is disable so we will not have the rights from the root dir messing up with the rights set on the sub folder. We did a copy of the acls from the old server to the new:

```
icacls c:\windows\ /save AclFile /T /C /Q
icacls c:\windows\ /restore AclFile /T /C /Q
```

more on that [here](http://virot.eu/save-and-restore-ntfs-permissions-using-icacls/)

Admins do not seem to have the issues (maybe because they can create files and folders directly in the root dir of the share). But while the network drive does not work properly users can create files and folder using the **UNC path** to the share. So it's not about rights.

**Server fault?**

The issue is universal as users from all versions of windows (clients win7 and win10, TerminalServer 2012R2 and 2016). I ran a wireshark to understand what was actually going on a client when trying to create a file:

```
SMB2 - Create Request File  
SMB2 - Create Response, Error : STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND  
SMB2 - Cancel Request 
SMB2 - Notify Response, Error : STATUS_CANCELLED
```

Seems that the SMB does not respond properly (but only with non admin users).

I would appreciate any help to understand what's going on and how to fix it.

Comment: UPDATE : while I was writing the post someone sent me this link (http://clintboessen.blogspot.com/2016/07/bug-with-windows-7-and-access-based.html) describing a similar issue. I will update my post if anything is changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solve by adding the "read permission" on root dir as mentionned http://clintboessen.blogspot.com/2016/07/bug-with-windows-7-and-access-based.html